# Finding the binary's name after package installation

Tags: homebrew, 7zip

When I installed 7zip via home brew (Formula `sevenzip`), i noticed that i cannot run it via `sevenzip` and even `brew info sevenzip` did not tell me the name of the binary.

Only after looking in the [script file on Github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/sevenzip.rb) I noticed a command `7zz` but there must be an easier way to find out the binaries or commands associated with a homebrew package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest I know is:

```
brew ls PACKAGE
```

and you can normally see it pretty quickly. Personally, I use `p7zip` as `PACKAGE`.

---

Alternatively, as `brew --prefix` tells you where binaries are installed (via symlinks), you can find the newest installed binary with:

```
ls -lrt $(brew --prefix)/bin
```

and it's the last one listed.